# Can't install my own gem via bundler, but can install with rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've created and pushed a gem to rubygems. I can install using:

```
'gem install mygem'
=> mygem installed
```

..and..

```
# Gemfile
gem 'mygem', git: 'git@github.com:me/mygem.git'
```

But if I put only `gem 'mygem'` in my Gemfile and `bundle install`, I receive this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find gem 'mygem (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

The gem was pushed to rubygems 3pm GMT. Not sure if the metadata bundler is fetching is the same as metadata used with `gem install`.

Before adding `mygem` to the Gemfile, I have successfully `bundle install` 30 other gems. Also note the `available on this machine` part. Why not `in any sources` like I've seen many times before?

```
Bundler version 1.2.2
```

Comment: Just run into same problem. Igust put 'gem 'iso_3166'' in the Gemfile. I do install the gem from command line (gem install iso_3166', then run bundle, in which case it works fine. But if I unustall local gem, bundle fails. The same trick works on production. Hope this is a temporary problem with rubygems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction: after some time my just added gem appeared where bundler looks for them. Apparently gem lists bundler use are being updated rarely. So, with gems under development, just use :git notation in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'iso_3166', :git => 'git@github.com:sergeych/iso_countries.git'
```